# How to use PapaParser to parse xls files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xls

I used react papaparser to upload the xls file, but the parsed content of the xls file after uploading was garbled. Even if I specify accept: application/vnd.ms Excel, it is still invalid. Thank you very much for any help!

here is my coding:

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react';

import { useCSVReader } from 'react-papaparse';
import { ParseConfig, ParseResult, Parser } from 'papaparse';

const styles = {
  csvReader: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10,
  } as CSSProperties,
  browseFile: {
    width: '20%',
  } as CSSProperties,
  acceptedFile: {
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    height: 45,
    lineHeight: 2.5,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    width: '80%',
  } as CSSProperties,
  remove: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    padding: '0 20px',
  } as CSSProperties,
  progressBarBackgroundColor: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  } as CSSProperties,
};

export default function CSVReader() {
  const { CSVReader } = useCSVReader();

  return (
    <CSVReader
      onUploadAccepted={(results: any) => {
        console.log('---------------------------');
        console.log(results,'-=-=-=');
        console.log('---------------------------');
      }}
      accept={'application/vnd.ms-excel'}
      
    >
      {({
        getRootProps,
        acceptedFile,
        ProgressBar,
        getRemoveFileProps,
      }: any) => (
        <>
          <div style={styles.csvReader}>
            <button type='button' {...getRootProps()} style={styles.browseFile}>
              Browse file
            </button>
            <div style={styles.acceptedFile}>
              {acceptedFile && acceptedFile.name}
            </div>
            <button {...getRemoveFileProps()} style={styles.remove}>
              Remove
            </button>
          </div>
          <ProgressBar style={styles.progressBarBackgroundColor} />
        </>
      )}
    </CSVReader>
  );
}
```

[The result printed by this onUploadAccepted callback function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arYHs.png)

And I discovered a problem:
Create a new txt inquiry, then edit the content, and finally modify it to xls format. At this time, the parsing of the uploaded xls file is normal;

However, if you directly create an xls file, edit the content, and ultimately upload the xls file, the parsing fails

Comment: papaparse doesn't parse xls as far as I can see

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. there are few things that need to be clarified before we proceed. one of them is that a csv **is not** an excel file (`xls`/`xlsx`). even microsoft excel itself has multiple different formats including but not limited to the binary format and OpenXML format of which each of them divided into many revisions.

Comment: I saw a prompt on the official website that supports uploading xls files, but as you mentioned, it cannot be parsed correctly, or I did not use the correct method。
https://react-papaparse.js.org/docs
“acceptis a property to be used to set MIME type for CSV. Default is 'text/csv, .csv, application/vnd.ms-excel'.”

Comment: @xifeng which part [in the docs](https://github.com/Bunlong/react-papaparse) says it can open excel? i am curious, to be honest. you could ask on their github issue for your particular problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll verify it. Thank you very much